# Elementary question in partial differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let's say we have a function of the [form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) $f(x+vt)$ where $v$ is a constant and $x,t$ are independent variables. How is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ equal to   $f$?

If I let $u=x+vt$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f/\partial t}{\partial u/\partial t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$
 but I cannot infer that $ \frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} =  f$ unless I assume the form of D'Alembert's Solution to be the harmonic (exponential). For the general solution I do not know how this was arrived at.

Edit:
I still don't get it, as the context does not help. But I assume since it is a physics text, $f$ can be written as a Fourier series/integral of exponentials. Assuming that, the above holds.

Comment: You are correct. Where did you see it written that you can make this inference?

Comment: There is a function $f:\ s\mapsto f(s)$ of one variable and a function $u:\ (x,t)\mapsto f(x+vt)$ of two variables. All you can say is that $${\partial u\over\partial x}={1\over v}{\partial u\over\partial t}=f'(x+vt)\qquad \forall x, \ \forall t\ .$$

Comment: Are you by any chance of south asian descent? Your username "kuch nahi" means "nothing" in some sense in urdu/hindi

Comment: @Tyler Yes (hindi). As I wrote in chat an hour ago, it is a close approximation of my progress in mathematics.

Comment: @Christian What does the $'$ in $f '$ indicate, ie, $\frac{d}{dt}$ or $\frac{d}{dx}$ or either??

Comment: @user45664: It means the derivative of $f$, whatever the name of the single independent variable.

Comment: @Christian So in $f'(x+vt)$ how would one know if its wrt $t$ or$x$? (this has caused me problems before) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - you can't infer that $f'(x) = f(x)$ unless $f$ is exponential, i.e. if $f(x)=A\exp(x)$.